# Local Notification on offline (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want to receive a local notification in my app (swift) when I'm not connected to Internet and I have some information registered in my Local Data base.
Is it possible to do that please?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using userlocalnotification

Comment: from ios 10 you can use User Notifications Framework. You check this link for tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/ios10-user-notifications-guide/.

Comment: check this tutorial for local notifications
http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

Comment: why don't you just try to do that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local Notification doesnot requires internet.
About Local Notification from apple developer site

Local notifications give you a way to alert the user at times when your app might not be running. You schedule local notifications at a time when your app is running either in the foreground or background. After scheduling a notification, the system takes on the responsibility of delivering the notification to the user at the appropriate time. Your app does not need to be running for the system to deliver the notification.

For more info check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html) link. You can also check [this](https://www.appcoda.com/ios10-user-notifications-guide/) link for tutorial.

Comment: Thank you these is the answer I'm looking for :)

Comment: M glad I could help you!!

Comment: yea the problem with this is the "appropriate time" decided by apple that might not be time useful

Answer (score 1):

do like this :

```
    public func presentNotification(_ notifAction: String, notifBody: String) {
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    let applicationState = application.applicationState

    if applicationState == UIApplicationState.background {
        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.alertBody = notifBody
        localNotification.alertAction = notifAction
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
        application.presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotification)
    }
}
```

UIApplicationState has these states :

```
    case active

    case inactive

    case background
```