# Can we detect if internet in turned off by the user in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, internet-connection

I am creating an application in which the location is continuously sent to the server in X minutes. Now the issue is if the user turns off the internet while in background or suspended mode, Can we send a local push notification?

Comment: I suspect you want this, but obviously notifications only will work when you are in the foreground. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-macos

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get notification in local, Go through this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1) for your refrence. 
Hope this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345432/local-notification-on-offline-swift) will help you.